# Reason of calling router.navigate() function within resolve

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i am looking into some code that looks like the following:

```
export class RouteGuardService implements CanActivate, Resolve<any> {

  private readonly startPage = 'start'

  constructor(private router: Router)

  public async canActivate(...) {
    ...
  }

  public async resolve(...) {
    if(...) {
      this.router.navigate([route.routeConfig.path ? route.routeConfig.path : this.startPage] ...)
    }
  }
}
```

What could be the reason of calling this.router.navigate() inside of the resolve() function? What are proper use cases where we need to do something like this?

Comment: Maybe the reason is that for specific data you cannot display that component and you need to display something else?

Answer (score 1):

Generally Resolved is used to prepare data before you redirect your route. In above situation, The best practice you can define your route in your utility or common helper service so the redirects will be smoother.